Can MUXs or their channels be sperate busses?
I am doing a little project with some MUXs. PCB is currently being built; I'm waiting for it to be shipped out to me. I have multiple MUXs on my board (TCA9548As). They are connected to a master pair of SDA and SCL lines, with pull up resistors, that are connected to a raspberry pi. Each of the 8 channels on the MUXs have their own pair of SDA and SCL pull up resistors. Does this mean that each channel on each MUX has its own bus? Or is there still 1 singular bus that has to be activated in my code or is each MUX its own bus? Here is the schematic I based each MUX's design on from the datasheet found at TI Datasheet for TCA9548A


What do you mean by the question? As in real physical hardware it's just a mux or several muxes on a single bus. Your Python library may give you handles to virtual I2C bus instances that refer any bus segment behind the mux as a bus which means you can have 24 sensor instances and give each of them a bus object given by the library so the sensor object does not know or care that the mux object handles switching to that specific bus instance. So is this being confused about hardware or the software framework and the programming environment it provides to you?

I mean, I can't understand this part : "Or is there still 1 singular bus that has to be activated in my code or is each MUX its own bus?", how do yourself understand or define what those concepts about a "bus" or "activating" it means?

By 1 singular bus I meant is there 1 master bus that I need to be dealing with in my firmware or do I need to worry about each channel creating a bus that had to be dealt with in my code. I understand a lot better in terms of how it works based off the answers a couple other people gave my question and based on your explanation from your first comment. Thank you.

As far as your MCU I2C peripheral is concerned, you still have only one bus.
What the TCA9548A allows you to do is select which I2C devices are connected to the bus at any given time.
This is useful when you have multiple devices with the same I2C address, so they can't exist simultaneously on the bus. What you'd do is have one of each on individual branches created by the TCA9548A.
The additional I2C pull-ups can be placed on the branches if you need slightly different pull-ups on the individual branches, based on trace length or capacitance of the I2C devices in that branch. You may also want to allow some branches to operate at higher speeds while others might have device which don't support that speed. In simple applications, you could probably skip the pullup resistors on the branches. When you do put them, though, remember that if multiple branches are enabled simultaneously, all the pullup resistors in activated branches will operate in parallel. I would strongly recommend ensuring you have at most one branch activated at any given time unless you know what you are doing and really need it.
As for your firmware, when you do things like an I2C device search, remember that you will only find those I2C devices on currently activated branches. Similarly, when you wish to communicate with a specific I2C device, you would have to ensure the correct branch is activated. Activating/Deactivating a branch will involve you communicating with the TCA9528 over I2C and setting the appropriate registers.
General I2C sample code will identify a devices by address alone, or with address + I2C bus number (if your MCU has multiple). When using a mux such as this, remember that you should include the branch number when specifying a device. Your code should also ensure the mux is correctly configured before you try to communicate with an I2C device.
Since this is typcially used when the same I2C address exists on multiple branches, remember that if you forget to configure the Mux before starting your I2C transaction, you might still get a seemingly valid response - but it might be coming from a different I2C device than what you intended.

Thank you very much for that informative response. I will make sure my firmware activates then deactivates one channel at a time correctly so that I don't run the risk of all of my pull up resistors activating at once in parallel.

@BeauRaley But the point of the Adafruit Python "driver" or "module" or the "framework" it provides is that you don't need to do it yourself, as the driver can give you eight "bus instances" per chip that when used will simply switch the mux for you, and no single sensor driver will notice any difference if you give it the "real I2C" bus instance or the "fake I2C" bus instance behind the mux. It's about the software interface you are given. In hardware, one bus, with sections that can be switched in and out as needed.

The TCA9548A is a passive switch; all active channels are directly connected to the master bus. This means that all devices on all active channels are directly visible and accessible by the master, and that the pull-up resistors on all active channels act in parallel. (You typically want to limit the total I²C pull-up current to no more than 3 mA.)
You can activate multiple channels at once, but you would not want to do this if there are devices with the same I²C address.

Indeed, not if there are devices at same addresses, or too much bus capacitance, or too much pull-up current. If it happens that the bus is jammed and it cannot be communicated on it any more, the only way out is the physical reset pin on the mux.
